# Excel VBA - if activeworkbook is thisworkbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in a workbook assigned to shortcut `CTRL + S` (intentionally), which runs a few things before saving the file, however this shortcut is picked up by any other document whilst this one is open.

Can you directly test if the `Activeworkbook` = `ThisWorkbook` so this is ignore when using any other workbooks?

```
Sub ShowHiddenSheets()
If ThisWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook Then
    `code stuff
End If
Exit Sub
```

Comment: Maybe something like this? `If ThisWorkbook.Fullname = ActiveWorkbook.Fullname`

Comment: FYI - Instead of "binding" the macro to `CTRL+S`, there's a [`Workbook BeforeSave()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx) event.  You may prefer to use that, since the `CTRL+S` may not necessarily run before the workbook is saved.  Using the event almost guarantees the code will run before it's saved.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks but the reason its bound to CTRL + S instead of `BeforeSave` is that this file is used by others that have an Add In on their excel which changes something in the file before saving, and I have no control over this but it stops me being able to use `BeforeSave` hence the workaround.

Comment: Use `Is` rather than `=`

Comment: @Rory spot on thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than doing any checks, Add this to the required workbook:

```
dim w as Workbook

set w  = ThisWorkbook
```

then within your modules, reference w.
For example:

```
with w.sheets("Sheets1")
```

This will ensure the macro only runs in that specific workbook, and not the others